# Is there a router that can take a wireless signal, and connect wired devices?

Tags: router, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have several devices that can only connect via wired connections. My ISP supplied router is more or less fixed in position, and bringing a wire from these devices to the router's current position is not practical.

Is there a router that can connect to the network wirelessly, which I can then connect wired devices to it?

Comment: I don't mean to be obnoxious, but if my answer below is not acceptable, you should clarify this---I'm willing to explain more...

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are looking for is called a "wireless bridge" [see Edit 2 below]. You can buy specially-designed wireless bridge devices for lots of money ($100 to $200 or more), or you can find an old wireless router you aren't using that's compatible with DD-WRT. (The latter option can be free if you already have an old, compatible router.)

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) is open-source router firmware that has the nice little feature (which I've made use of quite recently in a situation probably similar to yours) of being able to set the router to act as a wireless bridge. You simply configure the router via a typical web interface to connect to your already-active wireless network, and then any device you wire to the DD-WRT router will be connected to your network.

I would recommend starting from DD-WRT's [wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

[Edit 1] In case you're looking for a specific router suggestion: When I did this, I used an old Belkin router, but I've heard that the [Linksys WRT54GL](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=linksys+wrt54gl&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=5053734383126367789&ei=UQauTMLpAs3pOf_BhNUP&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDMQ8wIwAA#) is an excellent router on which to use DD-WRT, as well as in its own right.

[Edit 2] Per @bbaja42 in the comments, [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge) is an informative page at DD-WRT's wiki explaining some differences between an actual bridge device and a client router.

Comment: Yes, I did that with Dlink DIR-300, which was for ~$25 at the time.

Comment: small correction; it's not wireless bridge it's called wireless client mode

Comment: [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) can also act as a wireless bridge, and according to some people, is more stable than DD-WRT. It's not supported on as many routers, but for those that do support it, it's quite nice.